# Cycles - Using 2x HDRI for better lightning causes overexposed HDRI trough glass

Tags: hdri

I am using same HDRI, once for background and once for natural lights in my interior render:
[image]

The problem is when looking trough glass material the HDRI is over exposed.

Result outside glass material:
[image]

Looking through glass results in this:
[image]

Is there a setting in the glass material that will improve this? My glass material:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your world shader - the *Is Camera Ray* disables the (bright) look for the environment, but transparency shows the "true (bright) colors - the *Is Glossy Ray* on the second Mix Shader works to hide the bright image, even through glass:

[image: BrightGlass]

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine the *Is Camera Ray* with the *Is Transmission Ray* from the *Light Path* node. You can do this with a *Math* node set to *Maximum*, since both outputs are either 0 or 1 you will always get 1 unless both outputs are 0. However, for realistic lighting it is absolutely correct that it is overexposed - inside a room you have to use a higher exposure in a real camera so that the room isn't too dark, and in this case the outside will be overexposed through the window.

[image: mixing backgrounds]

This doesn't change the overexposed look on the outside. But as I said, for realistic lighting it would be normal that you set a lower exposure for the outside and a higher exposure for the inside - and I don't mean the strength of the background shader, but the *Exposure* settings in either the *Color Management* or with an *Exposure* node in the *Compositor* for example.